# jQuery show/hide to cycle through tables

Tags: jquery, animation

I need to set up jquery to cycle through tables, making sure it shows/hides the right one.

The basic HTML structure is:

```
<p><a href="#" class="month-next">Next Month</a></p>

<table class="month-show"><tr><td>blurb</td></tr></table>
<table class="month-hide"><tr><td>blurb</td></tr></table>
<table class="month-hide"><tr><td>blurb</td></tr></table>
<table class="month-hide"><tr><td>blurb</td></tr></table>
```

etc

So in jQuery so far I have:

```
$(".month-next").click(function () {
 $("table.month-show").hide();
 HERE I NEED SOME CODE TO ONLY SHOW THE NEXT TABLE IN THE HTML .show();
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".month-next").click(function () {
 $("table.month-show").hide().next().show();
 return false;
});
```

you might also want to change the classes, so that the next call will function as well (**edit:** inserted changes suggested by **[Mark Schultheiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125981/mark-schultheiss)**):

```
$(".month-next").click(function () {
    $("table.month-show")
        .hide()
        .removeClass("month-show")
        .addClass("month-hide")
        .next()
        .show()
        .removeClass("month-hide")
        .addClass("month-show");
    if ($("table").hasClass('month-show').length < 1) {
        $('table').eq(0).addClass('month-show');
    }
 return false;
});
```

Comment: Ok, far better than my answer. Far more fluent. However doesn't take care of cycling back to the first item when the last is visible :P

Comment: probably needs a check at the end prior to the return: if($("table").hasClass('month-show').length < 1) $('table').eq(0).addClass('month-show');

Comment: @Jamiec .. and therefore no better than your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a working example of how I would it: http://jsbin.com/ogika

CSS:

```
.month.hide { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<p><a href="#" class="month-next">Next Month</a></p>

<table class="month"><tr><td>a</td></tr></table>
<table class="month hide"><tr><td>b</td></tr></table>
<table class="month hide"><tr><td>c</td></tr></table>
<table class="month hide"><tr><td>d</td></tr></table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $(".month-next").click(function () {
        var months = $(".month"), numMonths = months.length, curr = 0;
        return function () {
            //Hide the current table, by adding the 'hide' class
            months.eq(curr).addClass("hide"); 

            //Get the index of next table in the list
            curr = (curr + 1) % numMonths;  

            //Show the next table, by removing the 'hide' class
            months.eq(curr).removeClass("hide"); 
        }
    }());
});
```

---

In the above code, `months` is the list of tables...which in this case, holds 4 elements; and `numMonths` is the number of elements...ie, 4.

The 'magic' of the above code is this line: `curr = (curr + 1) % numMonths;`

That line gets the index of the next element to be displayed, and it works in a circular fashion.

Let's take an example:

```
   0     1     2     3
=========================
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
=========================
```

Now, let's say `curr` is 0:

```
   0     1     2     3
=========================
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
=========================
   ^

//curr is currently 0
curr = (curr + 1) % numMonths; //(0 + 1) % 4
//now, curr is 1

   0     1     2     3
=========================
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
=========================
         ^
```

After that line of code is executed, `curr` becomes 1: (0 + 1) % 4 = 1.  This means that the next index of the element to be displayed is 1.  Therefore, we get the next element and show it, by removing the `hide` class: `months.eq(curr).removeClass("hide");`

Now let's look at the example where `curr` is the last element: 3

```
   0     1     2     3
=========================
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
=========================
                     ^

//curr is currently 3
curr = (curr + 1) % numMonths; //(3 + 1) % 4
//now, curr is 0

   0     1     2     3
=========================
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |
=========================
   ^
```

As you can see, `curr` is now 0...and thus the cycle continues.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This should work (and even takes care of cycling). You may have to make some slight adjustments due to other markup on tyour page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".month-next").click(function () {
     var $monthShow = $("table.month-show");
     var $monthNext = $monthShow.next('table.month-hide');
    if($monthNext.length == 0){
        $monthNext = $('table.month-hide:first');
        }
     $monthShow.removeClass('month-show').addClass('month-hide');
     $monthNext.removeClass('month-hide').addClass('month-show');
     return false;
    });

});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.month-show{ display:block;}
.month-hide{ display:none;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><a href="#" class="month-next">Next Month</a></p>

<table class="month-show"><tr><td>blurb1</td></tr></table>
<table class="month-hide"><tr><td>blurb2</td></tr></table>
<table class="month-hide"><tr><td>blurb3</td></tr></table>
<table class="month-hide"><tr><td>blurb4</td></tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".month-hide").hide();
        $(".month-next").click(function () {
            $(".month-show+table").addClass("month-show").removeClass("month-hide").show();
            $(".month-show").filter(":first").removeClass("month-show").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```